# Create input hidden type Element array in JavaScript and get values in Servlet but java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: javascript, servlets

I have html table and I want to get first column's all Ids in input hidden type element to send Servlet.

like this:

| price_id | price_list_id | product_id | tax  | agent_rate | counter_rate |

|       2  |             1 |          1 | 0.00 |      45.00 |        46.00 |

|        3 |             1 |          2 | 0.00 |      35.00 |        36.00 |

|        4 |             1 |          3 | 5.50 |     154.00 |       180.00 |

+----------+---------------+------------+------+------------+--------------+

So I have written following code:

First I have tried:

```
var priceId = null; // declared as a global variable out side the functions

function createPriceIdArray(){

    var r = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    var i = 0;
    var p = "";
    while(i < r.length){

        p = r[i++].cells[0].innerHTML;
        priceId = document.createElement("input");
        priceId.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
        priceId.setAttribute("name", "priceId");
        priceId.setAttribute("value", p);
    }
}
```

and submitted the form but not successful because i got  java.lang.NullPointerException

Then secondly I tried like this:

```
var priceId[] = null; // declared as a global variable out side the functions

function createPriceIdArray(){
    var r = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    var i = 0;
    var p = "";
    while(i < r.length){
        p = r[i].cells[0].innerHTML;
        priceId[i] = document.createElement("input");
        priceId[i].setAttribute("type", "hidden");
        priceId[i].setAttribute("name", "priceId");
        priceId[i].setAttribute("value", p);
        i++;
    }
}
```

in Servlet code:

```
String[] priceId;
priceId = request.getParameterValues("priceId");
out.print("<br> priceId[0] = " + priceId[0]);
```

Output:  java.lang.NullPointerException

I want to create the  element with hidden type and store html table's one column data i.e. priceIds (there are 10 records in table) so ten input hidden element should created and values assinged to them and submit the form.

But I can't do that

Please guide on this.

Comment: where did you added your hidden field `priceId` in the form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to attach the newly created Hidden elements to the form so that during the form submission they are also passed to servlet. Right now this is not happening and you are getting NullPointerException.

Change your javascript as below and it should work:

```
   var priceId; // declared as a global variable out side the functions

    function createPriceIdArray(){
        var r = document.getElementsByTagName("tr");
        var i = 0;
        var p = "";
        while(i < r.length){
            p = r[i].cells[0].innerHTML;
            priceId = document.createElement("input");
            priceId.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
            priceId.setAttribute("name", "priceId");
            priceId.setAttribute("value", p);
            document.getElementById("idForm1").appendChild(priceId);
            i++;
        }
}
```

Note that I have changed your priceId variable to normal variable from array and added newline which will add newly created hidden element to form. The id of the form should be matching in the javascript.

Let me know if this works for you...